# Does it matter where in my program I call atexit()?

Tags: c, return, sdl, atexit

Basically, I am writing a program in SDL.

This is part of the code:

```
    // create game window
    game.window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        160,
        144,
        0
    );

    if (game.window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Window error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    atexit(SDL_DestroyWindow());
    atexit(SDL_Quit());
    return 0;
}
```

My question is the following. Considering the procedural nature of C, what happens if `(game.window == NULL)` is the case and `return 1` executes. Does the program terminate with `return 1` without calling the `atexit()` functions that come after this `if`-statement?

Does the program still call `SDL_DestroyWindow()` and `SDL_Quit()`, which are both in `atexit()` functions despite the `atexit()` functions coming after the `return 1` in the `if (game.window == NULL)`-statement?

As far as I understand, C executes code from top to bottom, so how would it know to call the functions in `atexit()` at the end if `return 1` happens before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot destroy the window *before you know for true you have it created*  So the call to **atexit(3)** to register the function to destroy the window must be done **after you know the window exists**. (this is after the `}` closing bracket of the `if`)

The call to `atexit(SDL_Quit);` might be done once you have the SDL environment intialized (this is after it has been correctly inited, so it will be called only for a truly intialized environment) but it must be called **before** the call to register the destroy of the SDL window, as **atexit(3)** makes the functions you register, to be called in reverse order so it must first desroy the window and then close the SDL environment (and there will be no sense to call a function that destroys a window when the SDL has already been closed).

By the way, **atexit()** requires the function pointers, not the result of the function call.  Better to write

```
atexit(SDL_Quit);
atexit(SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

Than what you have written.

### NOTE

If the functions need parameters, better to write function wrappers to call them with the appropiate parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it wont call those functions registered with atexit().

To show this behaviour I wrote a small code snippet.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void bye()
{
        printf("Bye!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i = 1;
        if (i) {
                printf("Ending\n");
                return 0;
        }
        atexit(bye);
        return 0;
}
```

And this won't print the **"Bye!"**, as the **atexit()** is registered after the check for **i**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what is the best way to make sure `SDL_Quit()` is called if `(game.window == NULL)`? Is the best way to just state the function `SDL_Quit()` in the actual if statement? Or is there anything more efficient?

Comment: Why not have the at_exit() function calls above the check for game.window?

Comment: So if I call `atexit()` with all the necessary functions at the start of `main()`, won't it be called before `if (game.window == NULL)` is ever reached? Or does C keep track of `atexit()` until the program is terminated later on?

Comment: @Low-in-Sky: If your program doesn't call `atexit()`, no functions are registered with `exit()`.  You have to execute the call to `atexit()` to register the function.  It is not a compiler directive; it is a library function call.  You can make the call conditional (sometimes call it, sometimes not).   Etc. You can call `atexit()` multiple times with the same function pointer argument each time; your function will be called multiple times (once per successful call).  There is nominally an upper bound on the number of such calls, but the limit is at least 32 (and is usually not a hard limit).